# TypeError: this.state.article.map is not a function REACT

Tags: reactjs

How do I fix this error: TypeError: this.state.article.map is not a function

[image]

CODE:

[image]

Comment: try to `console.log(res.data)` and make sure it is an array. I'm pretty sure it is not.

Comment: It is not an array. But how do I put that data in an array? I have set article: []

Comment: paste how the response looks like.

Comment: {created: "2018-04-28T11:43:40.527Z", _id: "5ae45e6c8b45bb1e48508d1e", title: "Kiro Mekiq", img: "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/babylon5/images/7/7d/Kiro.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20080906055032", author: "Kiro Tvurdiq", …}author: "Kiro Tvurdiq"body: "Kiro MekiqKiro MekiqKiro MekiqKiro MekiqKiro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive a single object - a single "article". You need to put it as an element of the array:

```
this.setState({ article: [data] })
```